# Any method to use dotConnect without compiling the licence?

Tags: mysql, dotconnect

Im trying to use this http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/ with Indusoft Web Studio to connect from Windows CE to a MySQL database as its the only solution Ive found. The connection works (from what I see in the logs) but then a error message saying "License not found" pops up. Besides having terrible support, Devart for some odd reason does not understand Im using another IDE besides Visual Studio to compile this project. They keep telling me I need to add the resource to the project when IWS has nothing like this.

I tried to decompile the DLL but I cannot find a method to jump pass the "License not found" message.

Has anyone got this to work with a already complied program and just put the DLL in the same folder as their exe?

Ive tried their .NET Compact Framework complier as well but it did not work either. Their support is like I mentioned terrible. One of (if not the) the worst Ive had to deal with in YEARS.

Comment: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Licensing.html#compile

Comment: It's "Compile" not "Comply"... Very different meanings

Comment: @eggyal Did you read what I commented? I do not use VS for this project.